# PL/SQL Get result for each row using a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've just written a function to get the score of an image based on the average colour vs an input colour.  The purpose of this is so I can sort my images by relevance to their score vs the input color.

The function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_average_color_score
(
    p_red               NUMBER,
    p_green             NUMBER,
    p_blue              NUMBER,
    p_input_image       store_images.game_id%TYPE
) 
    RETURN DOUBLE PRECISION
IS
    -- Local variables
    l_average_color     ORDSYS.SI_AverageColor; 
    l_image_to_eval     ORDSYS.SI_StillImage;
    l_input_color       ORDSYS.SI_Color;
    l_blob_reference    BLOB;

    -- Determines how well the image matches the given color (%)
    r_avg_score             DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
    -- select the thumbnail into the BLOB data column
    SELECT thumbnail 
    INTO   l_blob_reference
    FROM   store_images
    WHERE  image_id = p_input_image;

    -- Build the SI_Color Object
    l_input_color := SI_Color(p_red, p_green, p_blue);

    -- Create the SI_StillImage to evaluate 
    l_image_to_eval := new SI_StillImage(l_blob_reference);

    -- Get the average color score %
    l_average_color := NEW SI_AverageColor(l_input_color);
    r_avg_score := SI_ScoreByAvgClr(l_average_color, l_image_to_eval);

    -- Return the % score
    RETURN r_avg_score;
END get_average_color_score;
```

Now I want to be able to evaluate the score of all images with one query and return them in a list from most relevant to least relevant, however I seem to have hit brick wall when it comes to implementing the logic for this query (possibly because I've spent the past 3 hours looking at the same code).

**EDIT:** I have tried to solve this problem by using a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT store_images.game_id, get_average_color_score(100,200,85, items.game_id) as score
  FROM store_images
  INNER JOIN items ON store_images.game_id = items.game_id
  WHERE items.store_id = 2
) ORDER BY score DESC;
```

However, the results which are getting outputted by SQLDeveloper are:

```
  GAME_ID  |  SCORE
---------------------
14          null
22          null
8           null
23          null
20          null
```

Where I'm expecting something along the lines of:

```
  GAME_ID  |  SCORE
---------------------
14          28.09345
22          33.44455
8           34.33345
23          52.03213
20          12.34543
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you don't know the next row until after you already score it (because of order by score), which means you can't use something like lag/lead for your X.

Comment: That's what I thought too - is there no other alternative? I want to do some row by row evaluation ideally

Comment: A subquery ? `select * from (select game_id, score_func(1, 2, 3, game_id) as score from store_inventory where store_id = 2) order by score desc;`

Comment: How did I not think of that as a solution! My bad,  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are passing game_id and using image_id to select the thumbnail so is the below sql correct

```
p_input_image       store_images.game_id%TYPE

-- select the thumbnail into the BLOB data column
SELECT thumbnail 
INTO   l_blob_reference
FROM   store_images
WHERE  image_id = p_input_image;
```

IF the above SQL is correct then change your query to check if image id is present

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT store_images.game_id, get_average_color_score(100,200,85, items.game_id) as score

FROM store_images
INNER JOIN items ON store_images.game_id = items.game_id
WHERE items.store_id = 2 
AND store_images.game_id in 
(select a.image_id from store_images a)
) ORDER BY score DESC;
```